# MarionetteJS: Using a collection with two or more views for different layouts

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a UI controller that for simplicity you can think as a Folder Tree where you can select multiple folders with checkboxes. The selection is saved in the model and "on save" there rare also a few actions triggered.

For usability reasons, we want to use two different visualizations of the same controller. The two UI controllers can in some layouts be present at the same time, in others only one at the time.

It would be nice to be able to reuse the same collection instance across the 2 UI controllers.

I can do this in one module pretty easily but how should I structure the code to make it work across different modules? I was thinking of having a module with models and collection classes, one module with View1 and another with View2, but where is the best place to put the instance of the collection and make it communicate with the rest of the world.

What are the best practices to share Backbone Models/Collections instances with two or more Views in Marionette?

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to have your entities (modules/collections) in a separate module, and have your various modules request them.

Example of an entity module (with collection definition and request handler): https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/entities/contact.js#L89

Example of requesting a collection (line 7): https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L7

In your case, the same instance can be reused, if desired. But make sure you have some mechanism in place to display reasonably fresh data (i.e. fetching the collection on the server to get the most up to date data).

You can use javascript's closure mechanism to do so, e.g.:

```
ContactManager.module('Entities', function(...){
  var contacts = new Entities.ContactCollection(...);
  contacts.fetch();

  ContactManager.reqres.setHandler("contact:entities", function(){
    return contacts;
  });

  ContactManager.commands.setHandler("contact:entities:update", function(){
    return contacts.fetch();
  });
});
```

Then, in your app, you'd use `ContactManager.request("contact:entities")` to get the contacts, and `ContactManager.execute("contact:entities:update")`.

The difference between a request and command is bascially semantic: requesting data from another part of the application, versus ordering some work to be done.

Using request-responses allows your application to be designed better (loose coupling, encapsulation). Attaching the data to `App.SomeNamespace.mycollection` will also work (I've done it in certain cases), but it leads to tight coupling, breaks encapsulation, and I wouldn't recommend it for large applications.

Comment: It looks pretty good. Question: in https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/entities/contact.js#L53 you are creating a new collection object. I was thinking to reuse the same instance of the object across the two modules. I can use the same mechanism to pass the actual instance and creating the object in the initializer of the module. Do you see any problems with that?

Comment: Reusing the object save some memory and update both the views each time that the collection is modified.

Comment: Another follow up question: in this specific case what is the advantage of using the RequestResponse object instead of simply  assigning the instance of the collection to App.SomeNamespace.mycollection ?

Comment: Thank you for the update. My feeling is that when an object is expecting something from another specific object, the decoupling is hard. If you have multiple workers, the request/response mechanism can provide an abstraction from which one get the job done  and maybe some adding some load balancing. But in case of one object to one object, I do not see any major advantage. The only one is not having to call the object with its name, that I would argue can be a disadvantage because now another engineer has figure out who is executing that command because it is not explicitly stated.

Comment: I just found this: http://victorsavkin.com/post/50669505752/marionette-requestresponse-considered-harmful that beside the alarming title, explain quite well what I meant. What do you think?