# how to share a model between different views with Backbone Marionette?

Tags: marionette

What is the simple way to share a model between two views ?

For example, in a simple mail app, my model contains for each message, the sender, the title, and the content of the mail. One of the view is the list of the messages with only the sender and the title. When you click on the title a new view is displayed with the content.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603363/marionettejs-using-a-collection-with-two-or-more-views-for-different-layouts

Comment: too complex. I'm searching desperately a simple example. I try to learn Marionette because it's meant to be a mean to build Backbone application with a good structure, and the docs are said to be better than Backbone. But when you really discover Marionette, the doc doesn't really help to figure out how each piece work together, and there is a lack of simple examples apps.

Comment: I'm trying to build a very simple mail app to learn, a button inbox, a view with the list of messages and a view of the message content when you click on an mail title on the list. It's really hard to figure out how many regions ? A layout manager ? or the App which manage the transition between views ? how to pass view's reference between view ? and so on...

Answer (score 7):

This is straight forward and requires no magic. Simply set the same model on multiple views. Something like this following:

```
var MyMailView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({}),
  MyOtherMailView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({}),
  modelInstance = new Backbone.Model();

var view = new MyMailView({model : modelInstance}),
  otherView = new MyOtherMailView({model : modelInstance});
```

Now you have a model shared between two views.